# What's the best way to burn a video file to a DVD?

Tags: dvd, video-editor, media

I have a few high quality video files in a number of formats.

I'd like to burn them so I can watch them on my DVD player.

I'd like a program similar to Nero, which can transcode the files and burn them to a DVD, as well as doing things like automatically splitting the video up into chapters.

Quality is very important: My files are 1080p blu-ray rips, and I'd like control over video and audio quality.

Comment: Which **Ubuntu** version?  Any previous experience with video editors, or just **Nero**?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think Devede would be best for you in this situation.  I use it myself regularly for multiple encodes to dvd with menus.  `sudo apt-get install devede`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options you could try, but I have never tried to transcode blu-ray myself

Firstly there is **Arista Transcoder** (available from the software centre)

**Kdenlive, Kino, Openshot, Avidemux, and Pitivi** are all intuitive and powerful multi-track video editors, including some of the most recent video technologies.

**K3b**  is a CD and DVD authoring application for the KDE desktop environment for Unix-like computer operating systems. (works great in Unity) It provides a graphical user interface to perform most CD/DVD burning tasks like creating an Audio CD from a set of audio files or copying a CD/DVD, as well as more advanced tasks such as burning eMoviX CD/DVDs. It can also perform direct disc-to-disc copies.

> sudo apt-get install k3b k3b-data libk3b6

Also available from the Software centre

**HandBrake** is an open-source program designed to convert MPEG video (including DVD-Video) into an MPEG-4 video file in MPEG-4 Part 14 (.mp4) or Matroska (.mkv) containers.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk handbrake-cli